# Ruby: What does the "!~" operator mean?

Tags: ruby

When declaring syntax such as:

```
a !~ b
```

where a,b are variables, what does it mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is negation of `=~`, a regex match.

```
"a" !~ /b/
# => true
```

It is useful when you want to check whether a string does not match a certain pattern. For example, if you want to check if string `s` includes only numbers, then you can do:

```
s !~ /\D/
```

Comment: Understand now, thank you :) Will accept as soon as I can do :p

Comment: Here's the documentation: [`Object#!~`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-21-7E)